# application taking time while launching first time on iOS 6.X.X

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6

application launch is taking 5-6 seconds on iOS 6.X.X versions in iPads. This works well on iOS 5.X. The default.png file remains a little longer on the screen with iOS 6.X.X.What could be wrong with loading.

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

```
if (orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{                                                         self.viewController=[[EBHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EBHomeViewController-LA" bundle:nil] ;
}
else if(orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    self.viewController=[[EBHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EBHomeViewController-PT" bundle:nil] ;
}

navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

there is no heavy code in applicationDidFinishLaunching.It takes time when we install the app & open it for first time /restarting iPad & launching application.

Comment: Any heavy code in applicationDidFinishLaunching??

Comment: show us your code from applicationDidFinishLaunching:

Comment: tried with basic sample app containing just a single view.It's also taking time.Is it an issue with ios 6.0.1 version??